# php_value output_buffering don't work normal

Tags: php, buffer

I don't why, but if I write this

> **.htaccess**

```
php_value output_buffering off
```

> **.php**

```
<?php
    echo "LVL OB: ".ob_get_level()."<br>";
?>
```

I get this: "LVL OB: 0" - It's normal i think, OB is off.

But, if I write this

> **.htaccess**

```
php_value output_buffering on
```

> **.php**

```
<?php
    echo "LVL OB: ".ob_get_level()."<br>";
?>
```

I get this: "LVL OB: 0" - Why I get 0? OB is on! Why? Explain me pls this moment.

P.S PHP 5.6 if is it important

Answer (score 0):

check if **output_buffering** is enabled on your server using phpinfo(),
it should display some integer value if not then you can enable it in php.ini first.
Once above is done then you do not have to add "**php_value output_buffering on**" in your .htaccess again

Comment: Wait! I'm curious behavior is php_value directive

Comment: yes, you can check refer this link : http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering

Comment: it's about output_buffering, not php_value

Comment: thats a way to enable output_buffering in your .htaccess

Comment: you can check this https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/php/using-php-directives-in-custom-htaccess-files/setting-the-output_buffering-directive-in-an-.htaccess-file

Comment: if I write `php_value output_buffering 4096` or any digits - work perfectly, it means `output_buffering` is working.

Comment: your last link doesn't explain my problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128120/discussion-between-anupam-and-maximpro).